# PulseAudio default.pa causes "No card found by this name or index."

Tags: configuration, pulseaudio, defaults

I have some lines in my `default.pa` that I want to use to establish a default for a device whenever it may exist, like this:

```
set-port-latency-offset bluez_card.FC_58_FA_B9_10_64 headphone-output 50000
```

The problem is that the `bluez_card.FC_58_FA_B9_10_64` card only exists after my computer pairs with my headphones. But if I put that line in my `default.pa` and run pulseaudio, I get

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: No card found by this name or index.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon due to errors while executing startup commands. Source of commands: /home/USER/.config/pulse//default.pa
```

Is there anyway to set up a default for a card/sink/source not yet available in `default.pa`?